# Remove dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked through some of the other posts but couldn't find an answer, so sorry if this is a somewhat stupid question.

I have a div
 which I add span elements dynamically to, like `<span id="agolf-squirecreek1.jpg">golf-squirecreek1.jpg</span>.` I need to remove these elements dynamically as well when clicked on. I have the click event linked with .live(), but the remove() wont work on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the onclick code that does the remove? It'll be easier to help you out.

Comment: This is the code i use to remove it. $("#d"+file).remove()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use .remove

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Or

Why dont you hide the element on click using

```
.hide()
```

or by putting style or class.  .add() or .addClass

or replace the html itself by `.html  or .text`

Comment: use firefox firebug and check are you passing the id properly. Or try to alert the id passing to js .                       http://www.dustindiaz.com/basement/add-remove.html   http://ajaxmint.com/demo/add-remove-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

This will remove a `span` when clicked within the context of `div#id`.

```
$('div#id').delegate('span', 'click', function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want to remove everything within an element you can use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) and furthermore, if you want to remove a span element but retain its event handlers/data object you can use [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) which is useful if you intend to add the element back to the DOM.

Comment: The div element contains a list of images, and i only want to remove the one element.

Comment: The above code only removes the span element that is clicked on.